# What is the best way to read user inputs via scanner?

Tags: java, algorithm, java.util.scanner

I use some approaches similar to the following one in Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] a= new int[3];
    
    //assign inputs
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
        a[i] = scan.nextInt();
    scan.close();
    
    //print inputs
    for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        System.out.println(a[j]);
}
```

However, generally the first input parameter is length and for this reason I use an extra counter (c) in order to distinguish the first element. When using this approach, the scanner does not read inputs one by one and checking the first and other elements in two blocks seems to be redundant.

```
// input format: size of 3 and these elements (4, 5, 6)
// 3
// 4 5 6    
public static void getInput() {
    int n = 0; //size
    int c = 0; //counter for distinguish the first index
    int sum = 0; //
    int[] array = null;
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter size:");

    //block I: check the first element (size of array) and assign it
    if (scan.nextInt() <= 0)
        System.out.println("n value must be greater than 0");
    else {
        n = scan.nextInt();
        array = new int[n];
    }

    System.out.println("Enter array elements:");
    
    //block II: check the other elements adn assign them
    while(scan.hasNextInt() && c<n) {
        if (scan.nextInt() >= 100) {
            System.out.println("Array elements must be lower than 100");
        } else {
            array[c] = scan.nextInt();
            c++;
        }       
    }
    scan.close();

    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        sum += array[j];
    }
    System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
}
```

My question is "how can I modify this approach with a single block (`while` and `for` loop inside `while`)? I tried 5-6 different variations but none of them works properly?"

Comment: I am not getting your question properly, can you rephrase it, with one 'while' you need to get all your input and 'for' is used for sum?? is that what you need?

Comment: I already see only one while and for loop.

Comment: @SabareeshMuralidharan Sorry, I updated the question (message parts). The problem is iterating and assigning values while checking all elements in it by distinguishing the first element also (the first element if size). Have a loo at pls?

Comment: @leoOrion Sorry, I updated. I mean 2 blocks, not while loop. The problem is also related to checking the elements. I mean that at first I need to check the first element and display message if it is nor fulfill the requirements. At this step I do not want to use `System.exit(0)` and continue the user try to enter again until the related element fulfills the requirements. Then I want to assign it to the array and come to next.

Comment: Added my answer, hope this helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps,

```
   public static void getInput() {
        int n; //size
        int c = 0; //counter for distinguish the first index
        int sum = 0; //
        int[] array;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size:");

        //check the first element (size of array) and assign it
        n = scan.nextInt();
        while(n <= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("n value must be greater than 0");
            System.out.println("Enter size:");
            n = scan.nextInt();
        }

        array = new int[n];

        System.out.println("Enter array elements:");

        // check the other elements and assign them
        while(c<n) {
            int num = scan.nextInt();
            if (num >= 100) {
                System.out.println("Array elements must be lower than 100");
            } else {
                array[c++] = num;
            }
        }
        scan.close();

        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            sum += array[j];
        }
        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
```

Output:

```
Enter size:
-1
n value must be greater than 0
Enter size:
4
Enter array elements:
1
2
3
4
Sum = 10
```

Comment: What is the point of `if(n<=0)` at `if (n <= 0) { while(n <= 0) {..} }`? Loop will check same condition so that `if` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I've optimized your code and fixed some bug.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size:");

        int n = scan.nextInt();
        if (n <= 0) {
            System.out.println("n value must be greater than 0");
            return; // need to break from here
        }

        int c = 0;
        int sum = 0; // no need for array
        System.out.println("Enter array elements:");
        // check the other elements and assign them
        while (c++ < n) {
            int next = scan.nextInt();
            if (next >= 100) {
                System.out.println("Array elements must be lower than 100");
                c--; // ensure can reenter the number
            } else {
                sum += next; 
            }
        }
        scan.close();

        System.out.println("Sum = " + sum);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had already force in order to prevent break and continue the app to get input.